# How to close and halt a jupyter notebook on google Colab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

If I am done with a jupyter notebook created on google colab and which was connected to one of its env with GPU, how do I close and halt it? Locally, I used to do this by clicking on File > Close and Halt. I just want to be considerate about using this great and free computing resource.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just close the tab, we'll take care of the rest.

Answer (score 2):

Go to:

Runtime >> Manage sessions

There you can view the active sessions

You can Terminate sessions or  Terminate other sessions than the current Colab notebook

Answer (score 1):

I recently found that

1. Menu > Runtime > Factory reset runtime actually terminate and decommission the VM releasing it back.

It will be faster than waiting for the system to reclaim it. This is handy if you are overusing your quota and want your "clock" to reset as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted to start from scratch (due to a problem), then you really really like to kill the session, this is a way to do this:

1) Menu > Runtime > Manage Sessions 
2) Find your session. Use notebook title and if GPU/TPU were used as hint. 
3) Click the big TERMINATE link/button

This is a cleaner "reboot" then just restart runtime. I sometimes got into inexplicable issues and able to recover from scratch when a restart runtime won't do.